# debugging: how to check what where my Python program is hanging?

Tags: python, debugging, trace

A fairly large Python program I write, runs, but sometimes, after running for minutes or hours, in a non easily reproducible moment, hangs and outputs nothing to the screen.

I have no idea what it is doing at that moment, and in what part of code it is.

How can I run this in a debugger or something to see what lines of code is the program executing in the moment it hangs?

Its too large to put "print" statements all over the place.

I did:

```
python -m trace --trace /usr/local/bin/my_program.py
```

but that gives me so much output that I can't really see anything, just millions of lines scrolling on the screen.

Best would be if I could send some signal to the program with "kill -SIGUSR1" or something, and at that moment the program would drop into a debugger and show me the line it stopped at and possibly allow me to step through the program then.

I've tried:

```
pdb usr/local/bin/my_program.py
```

and then:

```
(Pdb) cont
```

but what do I do to see where I am when it hangs?
It doesn't throw and exception, just seems like it waits for something, possibly in an infinite loop.

One more detail: when the program hangs, and I press ^C and then  (not sure if that is necessary) the program continues normally (without throwing any exception and without giving me any hint on the screen why did it stop).

Comment: Use the `logging` module to make the program tell what is doing and provide some status information.

Comment: Try placing `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before where you suspect it is hanging.

Comment: Well, the whole point of asking this question is that I have no idea where it might be hanging, and it takes about 10 minutes for the program to hang, so I just can't experiment too much because it'll take too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This could be useful to you.](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)  I usually do

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import program2debug
>>> pdb.run('program2debug.test()')
```

I usually add a `-v` option to my programs, which enables tons of print statements explaining what I'm doing in detail. When you write a program in the future, consider doing the same before it gets thousands of lines big.

Comment: Hmm, my program starts running as soon as I execute the line "import program2debug" so I have no chance to type the "pdb.run..." line.

Comment: @miernik: I think you'd need to put the main body of code of your program in a function called `test()` for what @Patrick is suggesting to work.

Comment: @miernik: That's why people do `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`... This ensures that when the program is imported as a module, it doesn't execute right away. Of course you can also call the method `test()` instead of main, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running it in debug mode in an IDE like pydev (eclipse) or pycharm. You can break the program at any moment and get to its current execution point.

Comment: Thanks, but both things you mention involve some graphical programs, which I can not install on the machine this runs, and the bug (hang) is network-dependent, and it doesn't appear on other machines.

Comment: Missed the last paragraph: The ^C thing might be a sign that your program waits for keyboard input...

Answer (score 0):

No program is ever too big to put print statements all over the place. You need to read up on the `logging` module and insert lots of `logging.debug()` statements. This is just a better form of print statement that outputs to a file, and can be turned off easily in production software. But years from now, when you need to modify the code, you can easily turn it all back on and get the benefit of the insight of the original programmer.